# how to link stylesheet in css

Tags: html, css, background

hi i tried to link an style sheet in my html for first time but problem is that it doesnt work i used this code:

```
 <link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but when want to choose an image as my background image i see no result

```
body {
background-image:url('images/back ground2.jpg');background-attachment:fixed;}
```

i tryed this before but no changes happened and i searched in w3s and i founed this suggestion(i wrote `<link href="css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` in my head tag
and also im using visual studio 2015

Comment: change url('images... to url('../images... as the path is pointing to a subfolder within the css folder.

Comment: @ jeff it still doesnt work and wisual studio suggests url file like this but when i use complete address nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your images folder inside css folder? If not you will have to give the location of the image as **background-image:url('../images/back-ground2.jpg');** where .. means parent directory of css directory.
Hope it helps. It would be helpful to find the error if you share the code and directory structure.